# save with file manager in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I am trying to save the emojis in this app that I learned in apple book but the problem is that I don't understand the next steps in the book,

create a static `loadSampleEmojis()` method that will create and return a predefined[Emoji]collection.You can use the list assigned to emojis in `EmojiTableViewController` as your list of items.

Update emojis to be initialised to an empty collection rather than a large sample collection.When the viewdidload() method is called you should check the documents/emojis directory for any previously-saved Emoji objects using loadFromfile().if they are found assign them to emojis.if not assign emojis to the result of loadSampleEmojis().

take a moment to think about when it might be appropriate to save your Emoji object.
in this case the central spot for your date is the emojis carry on the Emojitableviewcontroller with means it would be appropriate to call saveToFile(emojis:)whenever the emojis property is changed.
next, think about when it might be appropriate to load your archived Emoji objects.again,in this simple case theres really only one point where the archived data will need to be unarchived :when the first view loads.you should already be calling this method in the fist view controllers viewdidload().

this is what i wrote till now ,

```
 import Foundation


struct Emoji : Codable {
    var symbol : String
    var name : String
    var description : String
    var usage : String
    static let documentsdirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    static let archiveurl = documentsdirectory.appendingPathComponent("emojis").appendingPathExtension("plist")

    static func SaveToFile (emojis: [Emoji]) {
        let propetyencod = PropertyListEncoder()
        let encodemoj = try? propetyencod.encode(emojis)
        try? encodemoj?.write(to : archiveurl , options : .noFileProtection)
    }
    static func loadeFromFile () -> [Emoji] {
    let propetydicod = PropertyListDecoder()
        if let retrivdate = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveurl),
        let decodemoj = try?
            propetydicod.decode(Array<Emoji>.self, from: retrivdate){
   return decodemoj

        }
        return [Emoji]()
    }



}



import UIKit

class emojiTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var emojis : [Emoji] = [
        Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Grinning Face",
              description: "A typical smiley face.", usage: "happiness"),
        Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Confused Face",
              description: "A confused, puzzled face.", usage: "unsure what to think; displeasure"),
        Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Heart Eyes",
              description: "A smiley face with hearts for eyes.",
              usage: "love of something; attractive"),
        Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Police Officer",
              description: "A police officer wearing a blue cap with a gold badge.", usage: "person of authority"),
        Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Turtle", description:
            "A cute turtle.", usage: "Something slow"),
        Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Elephant", description:
            "A gray elephant.", usage: "good memory"),
        Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Spaghetti",
              description: "A plate of spaghetti.", usage: "spaghetti"),
        Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Die", description: "A single die.", usage: "taking a risk, chance; game"),
        Emoji(symbol: "⛺️", name: "Tent", description: "A small tent.", usage: "camping"),
        Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Stack of Books",
              description: "Three colored books stacked on each other.",
              usage: "homework, studying"),
        Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Broken Heart",
              description: "A red, broken heart.", usage: "extreme sadness"), Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Snore",
                                                                                    description:
                "Three blue \'z\'s.", usage: "tired, sleepiness"),
                                                                              Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Checkered Flag",
                                                                                    description: "A black-and-white checkered flag.", usage:
                                                                                "completion")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem


        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 52.0
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if section == 0 {
            return emojis.count
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emojicell", for: indexPath) as! cellviewTableViewCell

        let emoji = emojis[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(with: emoji)

        cell.showsReorderControl = true
        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func editbutton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let tablevieweditingmod = tableView.isEditing

        tableView.setEditing(!tablevieweditingmod, animated: true)

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return.delete

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     tableView.reloadData()
    }

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */


    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            emojis.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }



    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
        let movedEmoji = emojis.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
        emojis.insert(movedEmoji, at: to.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editcell"{
         let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let emoji = emojis[indexpath.row]
            let edittableview = segue.destination as! addTableViewController
            edittableview.emoji = emoji
    }
}
    @IBAction func unwindToemojitableview(segue: UIStoryboardSegue ){

        guard segue.identifier == "saveun" else {return}
        let sourseviewcontroler = segue.source as! addTableViewController
        if let emoji = sourseviewcontroler.emoji{
            if let selectedindexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                emojis[selectedindexpath.row] = emoji
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedindexpath], with: .none)
            }else {
                let newindexpath = IndexPath(row: emojis.count, section: 0)
                emojis.append(emoji)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newindexpath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }

}





import UIKit

class addTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var emoji : Emoji?

    @IBOutlet weak var symboltexfiel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nametexfiel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptexfiel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usagetexfiel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var savebutt: UIBarButtonItem!


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let emoji = emoji{
            symboltexfiel.text = emoji.symbol
            nametexfiel.text = emoji.name
            descriptexfiel.text = emoji.description
            usagetexfiel.text = emoji.usage
        }
        ubdatesavebutt()
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        guard segue.identifier == "saveun" else {return}
        let sym = symboltexfiel.text ?? ""
        let nam = nametexfiel.text ?? ""
        let de = descriptexfiel.text ?? ""
        let use = usagetexfiel.text ?? ""
        emoji = Emoji(symbol: sym, name: nam, description: de, usage: use)
    }


    func ubdatesavebutt () {
        let symbol = symboltexfiel.text ?? ""
        let name = nametexfiel.text ?? ""
        let descr = descriptexfiel.text ?? ""
        let use = usagetexfiel.text ?? ""
        savebutt.isEnabled = !symbol.isEmpty && !name.isEmpty && !descr.isEmpty && !use.isEmpty
    }

    @IBAction func ediittex(_ sender: UITextField) {
        ubdatesavebutt()
    }

}


    import UIKit

    class cellviewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var symbollabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var namelabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var descriptionlabel: UILabel!


        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }

        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

        func update(with emoji : Emoji) {
            symbollabel.text = emoji.symbol
            namelabel.text = emoji.name
            descriptionlabel.text = emoji.description
        }


    }
```

Comment: Only add _relevant_  code to your question - don't just paste in a whole file. That's disrespectful to other users.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you 'll need to add static method, that will return [Emoji], and contains your emoji preset (from emoji table view controller).

```
    static func loadSampleEmojis() -> [Emoji]{
    return [Your emojis array]}
```

After that, in Emoji Table View Controller, you'll need to define emojis like

```
var emojis = [Emoji]()
```

Next, in the viedDidLoad() you'll need to check if there is any data in your ArchiveURL? And if yes - to assign it to your emojis, otherwise assign preset.

```
if let savedEmojis = Emoji.loadFromFile() {
emojis = savedEmojis 
} else {
emojis = Emoji.loadSampleEmoji()}
```

And after that add

```
Emoji.saveToFile(emoji: emojis)
```

to tableView(_,moveRowAt:,to:), tableView(editingStyle) and unwindSegue.

Also, you need to correct :

```
static func loadFromFile() -> [Emoji]? {..}
```

Or control flow in viewDidLoad won't work.